# Display a different dictionary entry each day

Tags: windows-8, dictionary

I would like to improve my vocabulary through different ways and now I am looking for a vocabulary/dictionary app that can display a different word daily on the Windows 8 Metro platform.

I have installed a lot of apps trying to fulfill this requirement but without success.

Do you know any Windows 8 app that does that?

Answer (score 1):

### [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/) + [Gnometer](http://poiru.deviantart.com/art/Gnometer-1-3-0-3-182181512)

I use Rainmeter for desktop widgets. Among its numerous skins, Gnometer has a widget for "Word Of The Day", which displays a different English word each day along with its definition. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

<sup>(click image for full desktop)</sup>

You can reach this skin from the right-click menu after installing Gnometer:

[image]